# Dwarves not assigned to burrow still won't leave it?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I read through the explanations on how to set up a military, and in the new version of DF it seems that anything beyond training requires setting up burrows. I set up a burrow on the doorstep of my fortress intending to make it part of a patrol route, but as soon as I finished creating it, all the dwarves in my fortress dropped what they were doing and crammed into the 6x6 area around my floor hatches, where I had drawn the burrow. I didn't assign any dwarves to the burrow. What's going on?

Also, do burrows cover multiple z levels or just the one they're drawn on?

Comment: Do you have an alert going on? Addendum: Handy rule of thumb -- nothing goes multiple z levels 'cept adamantine tubes.

Comment: Could you paste your military and alert screens?

Comment: @Raven Actually, burrows *can* cover multiple z levels—if they're drawn across multiple levels with one area-define action, or if multiple define actions are done on multiple levels. @Nick, burrows won't cover multiple z levels if you've just drawn it on one level.

Comment: @Raven You're right, I had accidentally set that alert intended for my military to CIV, I guess that's what did it. @SevenSidedDie Thanks for the additional info!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an alert going on? Civilians will go to burrows they're not specifically assigned to if there is an alert active (this is an easy way to make sure your dwarves don't try to harvest socks from the enemy siegers).